# Cover a specific function with Coverage in Python

Tags: python, code-coverage

hope you are having a great valentine's day!

I'm having a problem with the **Coverage API** in Python. Given a function, I would like to get the covered lines in that function. The coverage api, however, returns the percentage of covered lines in the entire file I am working on. I leave here one example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import coverage

from example.transfer import send_money

cov : coverage.Coverage = coverage.Coverage()
cov.set_option("run:branch", True)

# Run the coverage tool
cov.start()

send_money(10, Account(), Account())

cov.stop()

total_covered = cov.report(morfs="example/transfer.py", show_missing=True)
```

The transfer file contains the **send_money** function, the class **Account** and a bunch of other small auxiliary functions. The output of the report provides the total coverage of the **transfer** file and not only of the function I want.

I was wondering if there is any setting I am missing, or any other API that can help with my problem.

Thankfully,
Paulo Santos

Comment: There's nothing in the coverage API to get data for just one function.  Why not run the command-line tool and look at the HTML report?

Comment: Hello! That's a good point. However I would to access the total coverage of the function in the Python Code. I need that value later. I have some ideas of solutions (such as the transverse the function ast, tag the associated code that was covered, and then manually calculate the coverage.

However, this does not seem an elegant and over-complex solution for something so simple like getting the coverage of a function. So I was wondering if there wasn't already any API that could do this.

Comment: Can you say more about how you will be using the coverage number later? What is special about this function that you want its coverage, but not the rest of the file?

Comment: I would like to assess the coverage performance of automatic test generation tools. Instead of that specific function I would actually have something like: f(*args), where f is an arbitrary function and args, a list of arguments for the function that was automatically generated.

Comment: You can access the coverage data directly: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.4/api_coveragedata.html  If you know the line numbers that make the function, you can get just those lines.

Comment: Hello Ned, thank you so much for your help! I will try to take a look at the CoverageData, although I already foresee two problems: 1. the coverage data does not include the lines for else statements; 2. it does not consider blank lines (although some code transformations could be done to remove these).

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Perhaps it would be better to use the XML or JSON report then.  Those include the reported coverage, so they understand the unexecutable lines like blanks, elses, and comments.